# Why all system calls in Linux passes arguments to kernel using "call by reference"?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, parameter-passing, system-calls

If we look at the `syscalls.h` file in Linux kernel, we can see that all most all the arguments of the system calls are passed by reference. For example

```
 asmlinkage long sys_open_by_handle_at(int mountdirfd,
                          struct file_handle __user *handle,
                          int flags);
```

Here, `file_handle` is passed as a pointer. Why not simple the value is not passed to kernel?

Comment: What value? Have you seen word *struct* there? What does it mean for your opinion?

Comment: I wanted to mean "call by value".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efficiency.

Many (most?) systems implement function calls by pushing argument values onto a stack.  If you pass a struct or any other complex data type by value, you'd need to copy it to the stack.  There's no reason to do this, since the kernel has access to the entire memory space of the process.  Aside from the copy cost, you'd also increase the stack space needed.

In addition, the kernel will need to copy any data it needs to retain into the kernel memory space.  The kernel can't rely on user space code behavior.  (It's also not going to free anything obtained from user space, which eliminates some any concerns over mixing up responsibility for reclaiming memory.)

Finally, realistically, coders working in the kernel need to be very comfortable with working with pointers.  There's really no advantage to passing by value once you're completely comfortable with pointers.

This part is a bit more of an opinion, but I think there's also a strong legacy effect.  The Unix kernel and C developed somewhat in tandem.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language) for some of the history. It's been a long time, but if I recall correctly, older versions of C wouldn't allow you to pass a struct by value.  Regardless, working with pointers was highly idiomatic in C (and I would say still is).  In other words, this is just how things have always been done.

Answer (score 0):

The memory space for user mode and kernel mode are different. When you make a system call, the MMU of the Linux subsystem makes sure that proper memory mapping of the user space process running in their own Virtual address space is done to the Physical address space of the kernel.

Variables in the user mode stay in the process' virtual address space. They can't just be passed in system calls and expected to get mapped in the physical address space .

This is what my understanding is. Would love to discuss and clarify if needed.

Comment: As per my understanding, memory assigned for a variable in userspace is virtual. So if a pointer is passed it will also be a virtual address. So on that case, does the kernel do some kind of translation(from virtual to real physical address)?

Comment: Yes, For every 4Kbytes of memory (for 32-bit systems) in the Virtual Address space , the Memory Management Unit (MMU)  retains a Page Table Entry in a table, through which translation of the Logical pages of the Virtual address space is done to the respective Page Frames in the Physical address space or RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Principally I understand that the `struct file_handle` parameter of the function `sys_open_by_handle_at(()` is an "in" parameter, i.e. it is not modified by the function. Therefore it could as well be passed by value. I see about three reasons why this is not done. All reasons are surely valid for this particular function; at least the last argument (K&R) applies to all struct arguments, in all system calls.

1. The struct can have a [size of e.g. 128 bytes](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/exportfs.h#L14) which would be slow to copy to the stack.
2. Passing a pointer obviates the need to know the struct definition on the caller side. The struct is an "opaque handle" filled by a previous call to `[sys_]name_to_handle_at()`. The caller doesn't want to and actually shouldn't be burdened with the details of the struct's contents. (Leaving the caller innocent obviates the need to recompile the program because the struct's layout changes. I can also imagine that the contents differs between file system types.)
3. Unix and even its open source complement Linux is older than C99. I suppose that for the longest time K&R C was the smallest common denominator C standard the kernel sources adhered to. In K&R C it is simply not possible to pass structs by value.